# How to tell if a route/method/view ever gets used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to clean up any routes, controller actions, and views that literally never get used in an application (that is, they'd be impossible to visit unless a user happened to guess the route).

(these sometimes appear because I think I'll need it, so set up the route, action, and view, then work takes a different direction and it doesn't get used)

The problem is how do I **confidently** tell if a certain route is ever linked to in an app?

#### What I already know

If the route looked like this

```
# routes.rb

'payments-setup-status' => 'user#payments_setup_status'
```

Then I could search the entire repository for `payments-setup-status` *and* for `payments_setup_status_url` *and* `payments_setup_status_path`. If I find no links to it, then assume it's unused anywhere in the app.

I am not sure what else I could do, or if there is some more 'intelligent' way of figuring out which routes/actions/views are not used in an application?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion offered in another forum:

- Use [coverband](https://github.com/danmayer/coverband) to find out which code in your app gets used and which code doesn't.
- If your app is in production, run coverband and view which code doesn't get run
- If your app isn't in production yet, run coverband in development, navigate around the app to get some idea about which code isn't getting used

Comment: Manually navigating around the app seems like a pretty flawed idea. I wonder if you can use coverband together with your integration/system tests (request/feature specs in RSpec)?